# Labeling links, Markdown style

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, urls, markdown

In Markdown, you can do

```
[google.][1]
...
[1]:http://www.google.com
```

In LaTeX, I've tried

```
\href{\ref{1}}{google?}
...
\label{1}{http://www.google.com}
```

But that doesn't work, and I'm tired of having long URLs in my document. How do you label and reference a URL?

Comment: FWIW, this is the default style in ConTeXt: see documentation for [`\useURL`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/useURL)

Comment: Is there any package I can import to get this functionality in regular LaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I've since written a package called [latex-markdown-linking](https://github.com/scottsievert/latex-markdown-linking) to include similar formatting.

```
\usepackage{hyperref} % required by linking.sty
\usepackage{linking}  % include linking.sty in your compile folder

% Markdown equivalent: [Bode Miller]:https://...
\SSdefine{Bode Miller}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_Miller}

\begin{document}
% Markdown equivalent: [Bode Miller] has won...
\SSlink{Bode Miller} has won 6 Olympic medals and 5 World Cup medals.
\end{document}
```

will give you

> [Bode Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_Miller) has won 6 Olympic medals and 5 World Cup medals.

Comment: LaTeX Error: FIle `linkg.sty` not found. When trying to import "linking" on overleaf.

Answer (score 7):

Here a small suggestion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\makrdownlink[2]{%
 \immediate\write\@auxout{%
   \string\expandafter\string\gdef\string\csname\space markdownlink#1\string\endcsname{#2}%
 }%  
}

\newcommand*\makrdownref[2]{%
 \@ifundefined{markdownlink#1}
  {\typeout{Undefined ref~markdownlink#1}\textbf{#2}}%
  {\href{\@nameuse{markdownlink#1}}{#2}}%  
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\makrdownref{2}{google}

\makrdownlink{2}{www.google.com}
\end{document}
```

The procedure can be simplified if you define your links in the preamble. Then you don't need to write something to the aux file.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution. In my document preamble, I wrote:

```
\newcommand{\sage}{http://www.sagemath.org}
```

Then, when I wanted to reference it, I used

```
\href{\sage}{This text will be linked to sagemath.org}
```